# Regex to validate Telephone number extension

Tags: javascript, regex

I have requirement to validate telephone number (TN) extension (Just extension only). The extension can be in 3-6 digit length and in 3 digit extension that should not follow 11. And yes other things, the extension should not have special chars and all zeros.

For example: 911, 311 etc.,

We have written the below one.

```
(?!0+$)[0-9](?!.*11).[0-9]*$
```

The issue with the above is

For 311, 211 --> Validation is pass.

For 38311, 2311 --> Those are 4 and 5 digit length extension and it can be suffixed with '11'. But the above pattern is not allowing it. How can I achieve that?

Comment: [`^(?!^0+$)(?:(?:(?!11)\d){3}|\d{4,6})$`](https://regex101.com/r/58hO8n/1/) is this what you're after ?

Comment: If the extension is a dedicated form field then you can easily use native comparison operators and the `.length` property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use:

```
(?!^((0+)|(\d11))$)(?=^\d{3,6}$).*
```

- `(?!^((0+)|(\d11))$)` - From start to finish make sure it's not all zeros nor a digit followed by `11`
- `(?=^\d{3,6}$)` - From start to finish make sure we are dealing with 3 to 6 digits
- `.*` - If the previous validations passed then it's safe to grab everything

https://regex101.com/r/eIVvvX/1

Answer (score 0):

For checking nonzero you can simply use `>` operator and for rest of rules you can use this pattern

[image]

```js
let data = ['911','311','38311','2311','000000','123111', '112']

data.forEach(v=>{
  console.log(v, '\t' , v > 0 && /^(?:(?:(?!11$)\d){3}|\d{4,6})$/.test(v)) 
})
```

---

For checking non zero you can use regex too, but i prefer the above method personally

[`^(?!^0+$)(?:(?:(?!11$)\d){3}|\d{4,6})$`](https://regex101.com/r/58hO8n/3/)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Seems the above regex not accepting '112,114 ...'

Comment: @Raja adding anchor inside negative lookahead will solve the issue solve the problem